# Merging nested hash with deep_merge using the same key

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to merge two hashes together, in doing so I thought I could use `deep_merge!` but it isn't giving me the desired output:

```
collection = {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>1886.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>184.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>2070.0}}

new_collection = {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>200.0}}

# running this line gives
collection.deep_merge!(new_collection)

{:foo=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>200.0}}
```

The desired output I'm after is:

```
{:foo=>{:amount_gross=>1986.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>284.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>2,270}}
```

Comment: What is `ret`, `a` & deep_merge!

Comment: @Salil apologies this was from a old snippet that I had before I pasted as a question. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: `deep_merge!` does not exist in either the Ruby core library or the Ruby standard library. So, it must have come from somewhere else that you are not telling us. Since you are not telling us, even after having been asked about it already, there is not much we can do to help you. You will have to take it up with the author of `deep_merge!` is you believe there is a bug, or read its documentation if you don't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The question was answered by myself and by Salil before your comment, which by reading doesn't add any benefit whatsoever.

Comment: You are asking for help with `deep_merge!`, but you are not telling us what `deep_merge!` is, and your desired output is not valid Ruby code, so it is really hard to understand what the problem is. In general, if you are asking other people to do your work for you, for free, in their spare time, it would be considered polite to provide the necessary information, especially when asked for it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this [`[deep_merge][1]`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge) or `[deep_merge!][2]` method, then try following

```
collection.deep_merge(new_collection) { |key, this_val, other_val| 
  this_val.class == String ? this_val : this_val + other_val
}
```

Note:- We have to add `this_val.class == String` otherwise we'll get `provider=>"totaltotal"` & also assuming each hash key will have value of same data type.

```
[13] pry(main)> collection = {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>1886.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>184.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>2070.0}}
=> {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>1886.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>184.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>2070.0}}
[14] pry(main)> new_collection = {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>200.0}}
=> {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>100.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>200.0}}
[15] pry(main)> collection.deep_merge!(new_collection) { |key, this_val, other_val| this_val.class == String ? this_val : this_val + other_val}
=> {:foo=>{:amount_gross=>1986.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>284.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"total", :amount_gross=>2270.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce, we're able to get around this by doing:

```
[collection, new_collection].reduce({}) do |sums, stats|
  sums.merge(stats) do |_, prev_hsh, new_hsh|
    prev_hsh.merge(new_hsh) {|_, prev_val, new_val| prev_val + new_val }
  end
end
```

Which outputs:
`{:foo=>{:amount_gross=>1986.0}, :bar=>{:amount_gross=>284.0}, :total=>{:provider=>"totaltotal", :amount_gross=>2270.0}`